# Задача на работу с API Википедии

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests

Задача состоит в том, чтобы брать из списка название страны на русском, а на выходе получить её код состоящий из двух букв.

Вот мой код:

```py
import requests
import json


a = ["Абхазия", "Австралия", "Австрия", "Азербайджан", "Албания", "Алжир"]
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    x = a[i]
    z = "http://api.geonames.org/wikipediaSearchJSON?formatted=true&title={}&lang=ru&maxRows=1&username=garagemca_raan".format(x)
    jsonstr = requests.get(z).text
    json = json.loads(jsonstr)
    codeval = json['geonames'][0]['countryCode']
    print('Country is ' + x +' Country code is {}'.format(codeval))
```

На выводе всё получается по-разному: либо ошибка AttributeError, но перед ней выводится код первой страны, либо KeyError без какого-либо вывода.

Answer (score 4):

Инструкцией `json = json.loads(jsonstr)` вы переопределяете модуль `json`, поэтому после первой же итерации получаете исключение.

***Исправленный код:***

```py
import requests
import json


countries = ('Абхазия', 'Австралия', 'Австрия', 'Азербайджан', 'Албания', 'Алжир')

for country in countries:
    url = f'http://api.geonames.org/wikipediaSearchJSON?formatted=true&title={country}&lang=ru&maxRows=1&username=garagemca_raan'

    response = requests.get(url)
    d = json.loads(response.content)
    code = d['geonames'][0]['countryCode']

    print(f'Country is {country}. Country code is {code}')
```

***stdout:***

```html
Country is Абхазия. Country code is MD
Country is Австралия. Country code is AU
Country is Австрия. Country code is AT
Country is Азербайджан. Country code is AZ
Country is Албания. Country code is IT
Country is Алжир. Country code is DZ
```